# Using jQuery to find list items containing specific text in nested lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, each

I am working on setting up a way to select or filter a list using radio groups of "modifiers" or attributes. The lists I'm filtering can be multi-level nested ul-li.

My eventual goal is to have only the intended list items with the correct attribute or text show, the others would be hidden.

In my example, I'm having issues with selecting only what I want. It's selecting the whole nested ul if there is an li that contains the text I'm looking for.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhottle/9BQcj/5/) I made

```
$('.refine').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {

    var sortattr = $(this).val();   

    $(".mylist li:contains('" + sortattr + "')").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('here');
    });
});

<form class="refine" role="form">
    <input type="radio" value="left" name="modifiers" id="reflatleft">Left
    <input type="radio" value="right" name="modifiers" id="reflatright">Right
    <input type="radio" value="unspecified" name="modifiers" id="reflatunspecifed">Unspecified
</form>                         

<ul class="mylist">
    <li>item misc header
      <ul>
        <li>item left</li>
        <li>item right</li>
        <li>item left</li>
        <li>item unspecified</li>
        <li>item somethings else</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item left</li>
    <li>item right</li>
    <li>item left</li>
    <li>item unspecified</li>
    <li>item somethings else</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/9BQcj/11/)

You just have to check whether there are any child elements in the `<li>`'s to be highlighted
so just adding a if construct would solve the problem

```
$('.refine').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {

    var sortattr = $(this).val();   

    $(".mylist li:contains('" + sortattr + "')").each(function() {
        if($(this).children().length == 0){
            $(this).addClass('here');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!, Fiddle works like I want, now gotta see if it'll work in my project.

Comment: @user1572121 use .children() instead of .find("ul")
its general and precise. i updated my answer accordingly

Comment: OK, that's not working for me in my project, your original did.

Answer (score 2):

Add default styles to `li`:

```
li{
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: One thing is needed also: `$(".mylist li").removeClass('here');` when clicked input radio.

Answer (score 0):

at first create an array like below

```
var myArray=new Array();
```

then

pust your contents like below

```
myArray.push(item you want to push);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why whole li is getting selected is because of ur selector.

Your current selector is '.mylist li'.

You code iterates to find the requested text, for eg. 'left' and it adds the css to the complete selector.

So instead of adding class to ".mylist li ul li" it adds the class to ".mylist li"
hence the whole outer li gets highlighted.

You can use **[.has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)** to iterate through the nested ul li