# Using jquery to find values that are regular expressions in a html select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to retrieve the index of html elements in a list using Jquery 3.4+.
The common solution can be found in posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372664/how-to-find-inside-a-list-element-by-attribute-jquery) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792913/using-jquery-to-find-list-items-containing-specific-text-in-nested-lists).

I have implemented it and it runs well until the values I am trying to retrieve are none others than regular expressions.
Here's a fiddle of what I have tried:

```js
//let myVar = $("#myList").find(`option[text='^.*\.xlsx'])`)[0].index;
let myVar = $("#myList").find(`option:contains('^.*\.xlsx')`)[0].index;
console.log(myVar+"");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select size="1" id="myList"> 
     <option selected style="width:100%;">^.+\.(txt|csv|xlsx)</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|bmp)</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.xlsx</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.docx</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.csv</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.pdf</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to add that I can't escape characters nor change the value of what I'm looking for.
Is there a way to get it working for any value regardless of it being a standard text, a regular expression or whatever could be injected in the search function?

Comment: it's not clear what you are actually asking. First of all does the attribute selector `[text=]` exist in jQuery? Isn't [it](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#contains1) `:contains('word')`? Secondly, the text is text.. there's no distinction between standard text or regular expression.. so can you please be more clear?

Comment: I am a beginner in html/js/jquery so my apologies if what I'm asking isn't clear. [text=] works for me but perhaps is this due to the environment I'm using. However I have included :contains as a comment, as you can see in the fiddle, and it produces the same result. What I'm saying and asking is: "I've tried this, it works well on standard text like "foo", "bar" etc... but doesn't when the values are regular expressions, is there a way to get it working in this case?"

Comment: `let myVar = $("#myList option:contains('\\^.*\\\\.xlsx')").index();` this will return 2. If that's what you are trying to achieve. Those backslashes are mixture of escape sequences. By the way I think a better and more clear approach would be to just iterate over the `#myList option` elements and check the text content of each one doing your own logic.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the original post I can't escape the characters. This is only a fiddle with a specific example but I'm actually receiving the value to search from a JSON and I don't have control over it. I will try a loop over the elements but it sounds like a lesser solution to me: it is more code and more "fiddling around" whereas there are tools that already exist and should be doing the job in 1 line. I'll try it if I have no other options though.

Comment: I added an answer that implements the logic needed to escape the backslash in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still using the same strategy adopting jQuery to select the element through the `:contains` selector https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#contains1

But you need to escape the backslash `\` replacing each one with `\\\\`

Here's a demo that is simulating the input data fetch grabbing it from a text input value:

```js
function fetchInput(){
  return document.getElementById('input').value;    
}

function search(){
  const searchTerm = fetchInput();
  const escaped = searchTerm.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');

  let index = $(`#myList option:contains('${escaped}')`)?.index();

  console.log(`index: ${index}`);
}
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Search</h1>
<input id="input" value="^.*\.xlsx">
<button onclick="search();">Search</button>

<hr>

<select size="1" id="myList"> 
     <option selected style="width:100%;">^.+\.(txt|csv|xlsx)</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|bmp)</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.xlsx</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.docx</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.csv</option>
     <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.pdf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tested it some more and as you pointed out earlier the main issue was to escape the characters. I was able to get it working thanks to your example so I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the snippet you provide there are few mistake.

1. `$("myList")` need to be `$("#myList")` because your select has id `id="myList"`.
2. You are trying to get option based on `text` attribute with `option[text='^.*\.xlsx'])` but you don't have text attribute in your `option`.
3. Your option text has `\` escape character so in your js you need `\\` for the equivalent `\` in html. Also, I noticed that `contains('')` retuned undefined while doing `contains('^.*\\.xlsx')` and you need `contains('^.*\\\\.xlsx')`.

I have created following workaround to get the index of option based on the text in option. See the following example:

```js
let myVar = $("#myList").find("option");

var itemIndex;
myVar.map(function(i, v) {
  if ($(v).text() == '^.*\\.xlsx') {
    itemIndex = i;
  }
});

console.log(itemIndex);

let index = $("#myList option:contains('^.*\\\\.xlsx')").index();
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select size="1" id="myList">
  <option selected style="width:100%;">^.+\.(txt|csv|xlsx)</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|bmp)</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.xlsx</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.docx</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.csv</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.pdf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Apologies for the basic mistakes, I'll fix them in the original fiddle. As I mentionned in the post, I cannot alter the value in the search so I can't escape the characters, or at least not by hand. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @Cedt I guess another answer does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to find the index of the option element that contains the text '.xlsx' when selected from the dropdown. The issue with your code is that you're using the `.index()` method directly on the selector, which returns the index of the first matched element.

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myList").change(function() {
    let selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
    let selectedIndex = $(this).find("option").index(selectedOption);
    console.log("Selected Index:", selectedIndex);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select size="1" id="myList">
  <option selected style="width:100%;">^.+\.(txt|csv|xlsx)</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|bmp)</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.xlsx</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.docx</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.csv</option>
  <option style="width:100%;">^.*\.pdf</option>
</select>
```

this will give you selected option Index.